# SSH overseas with Raspberry pi

Tags: ssh, network-programming, ip, raspberry-pi

I currently have my Raspberry pi setup with network connectivity and i can connect to it via local ip addres like this:
192.168.0.x

Is there anyway i use my puplic ip to ssh into my raspberry pi ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions to this problem.

1. If your ISP provides public ip, you can use dynamic DNS services from no-ip or dyndns  or any other equivalent service providers and you can forward port #22 to rpi ip using your router menu.
2. If your ISP doesn't provide public ip and you are behind NAT. You can make use of reverse remote ssh method mentioned in this link. But to access via this method, you need a server in between that's having a public ip. http://www.tunnelsup.com/raspberry-pi-phoning-home-using-a-reverse-remote-ssh-tunnel

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think a Dynamic DNS is usualy the way to go. I use FreeDNS and I think it's pretty good. [Instructions for setup](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1758930) by dentaku65:

> First of all register your account on [Freedns](http://freedns.afraid.org/menu/). Freedns offers a bunch of domain names, from my taste the best ones (or the ones easy to remember) are:
>
> - mooo.com
> - ignorelist.com
>
> Assume that you register: `your_host>.ignorelist.com`
>   Install inadyn:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install inadyn curl
> ```
>
> Open the url: `http://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/`
>   Login with your account
>   Select the link Direct URL beside .ignorelist.com
>   Copy everything from the right of the ? in the address bar (alphanumeric string)
>
> Create configuration file of inadyn:
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /etc/inadyn.conf
> ```
>
> And save this content:
>
> ```
> --username <your_username>
> --password <your_password>
> --update_period 60000
> --forced_update_period 320000
> --alias <your_host>.ignorelist.com,alphanumeric string
> --background
> --dyndns_system default@freedns.afraid.org
> --syslog
> ```
>
> Add inadyn to crontab:
>
> ```
> export EDITOR=gedit && sudo crontab -e
> ```
>
> Edit the file to add the following line:
>
> ```
> @reboot /usr/sbin/inadyn
> ```
>
> Reboot your PC
>   Wait 3 minutes
>   Check if inadyn is running:
>
> ```
> ps -A | grep inadyn
> ```
>
> Check inadyn behaviour:
>
> ```
> more /var/log/messages |grep INADYN
> ```
>
> Check if your host is up:
>
> ```
> ping <your_host>.ignorelist.com
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you may need to enable portfowarding on your router